# Javascript-Android get selected text script

Tags: javascript, android, html

I tried to get selected text from an html page on each touchend event in android device but am not able to get selected text.

Javascript code is :

```
if(window.getSelection)
{
    t = window.getSelection();
}
else if(document.getSelection)
{
    t = document.getSelection();
}
else if(document.selection)
{
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this in a webview ?

`window.getSelection()` returns the Selection object. You can get the text by calling `toString()`

```
if( window.getSelection){
   t = window.getSelection().toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to trigger an event in JavaScript when user selects text in android device and get the selected text.Because in button click the selection is gone so am not getting the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function right after a text selection, you can use the "selectionchange" event:

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", handleSelection);
```

It's working for android chrome and iOS safari (but not for android mozilla and opera).